# Difference between "да?", "так?", "не так ли?", "а?" as a tag question

Tags: словоупотребление, tag-question

> ..., **да**?
>
> ..., **так**?
>
> ..., **не так ли**?
>
> ..., **а**?

I've so far come across these four words functioning as a tag question, and I wonder how they differ in meaning and usage? In most languages, there are several different words for forming a tag question, each having a flavour of its own.

> ..., **верно**?

Comment: another one would be `что ли`, very colloquial and expressive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**..., да?** — "right?" ("is it true?")

**..., так?** — "right?" ("did I understand you correctly?")

The difference is that **да?** seeks to *confirm* some prior knowledge, guess, or suspicion, while **так?** generally double-checks the speaker's *comprehension*.

**..., не так ли?** — generic "doesn't it?" (and other forms)

**..., а?** — not *quite* sure it belongs with the others. You can add it to requests to signify insistence/pleading (**ну пойдём, а?**), to things that are formally questions, signifying either impressiveness (**как мы их обогнали-то, а?**) or frustration (**что за чертовщина, а?**), and to actual questions, signifying impatience (**вы вообще инструкцию читали, а?**) — but it doesn't work as something you can tag on to a *statement* to turn it into a question.

I'd add another one:

**..., правда?** — the sort of "doesn't it?" that prompts to agree with the speaker on some point expressed in or related to the statement.

Comment: Hi. Regarding "а", I have seen it following the rhetorical question: "Тогда почему ...? **А**?".

Comment: @alone-Zee Oh, that one. It's the sort of "huh?" you can add to something that's already a question (rather than turn it into a question by adding it), so, again, not quite a proper "tag". EDIT: then again, so are both my examples. I'll edit now.

Comment: So "..., **так?**" corresponds to "..., **is that it?**" in English, I take it?