# When to use "ведь так", as opposed to other tag questions?

Tags: словоупотребление, tag-question

> «Нельзя верить женщинам», **ведь так**?

As I understand it, "ведь" and "так" can both individually serve as a tag question: "isn't it?", "right?". But what about when they are coupled together? How is  "ведь так" nuanced compared to other tag questions?

[Difference between "да?", "так?", "не так ли?", "а?" as a tag question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/difference-between-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0-as-a-tag-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not entirely correct.

**Ведь** alone can't form a tag question.

"**..., так?**" compared to "**..., ведь так?**" (or "**..., так ведь?**" ) sounds stiffer and more demanding. **..., ведь так?** roughly means "*I feel you won't argue*".

Comment: Hi. Oh, I meant something like: "Приятно **ведь** получать плату за работу?". I find it interesting that  "ведь" can be used in the middle of a sentence like this.

Comment: @Alone-zee Hi. That's true. You may think that in the "ведь так" the word "ведь" also appears in the middle of the one word sentence "так?" And the meaning is the same: you express the hope that your interlocutor will agree with you (or even if he doesn't agree he will make you a favor and pretend he does).

Comment: Ah, I wonder if a sentence with "ведь" is close to the English phrasing: "..., isn't it? **Surely** you'd agree?". By the way, in the example sentence above in my comment, at what other positions can you place "ведь"?

Comment: @Alone-zee I can't tell for sure as I'm not so good in English, but something like this. May be you shall remove "isn't it" to make it sound softer. As for possible positions of "ведь", the most natural are "Приятно ведь" and "Ведь приятно", but you may try other positions. "Приятно получать ведь плату..." means you think it is nice to get paid, and not just thanked, for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Ведь** actually means "to know" although modern Russian speakers are often not aware of this fact and only use it as a emotional informal grammar addition. It can be used in the sentence to gently demand an audience to agree to the statement. It must precede or follow the subject or a verb in question. In your example "так" is a statement that can be translated as "yes" and "ведь" is attached to it.